# Firebase Auth using Google Sign-in for Web not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

I m just exploring Firebase. I ve set up Firebse Auth using Google sign-in. It just works perfectly in my local while running from my local server. I tried to push it to my github pages, the authentication part failed to work. I ve used signinWithRedirect(), provided the code below. The result of the request is always an object with user:null and it redirects to about:blank. Could someone help me out, thanks in advance.

```
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
  firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    currentUser = result.user;
    console.log(token);
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue here. That's happening because you didn't authorized your domain to run this operation. In the Firebase console, open the Auth section. 
On the Sign in method tab, add your domain to the OAuth redirect domains list.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays error message in the console is fairly straightforward.

[image]

> This domain (xxxx.vercel.app) is not authorized to run this operation.
> Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console ->
> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.

Head over to the **Firebase console** > **Authentication** section, then go inside the **Sign-in method** tab.

[image]

You will need to add your domain to the **Authorized domains** list.

[image]

Comment: Thank bro it helped me a lot. May God bless you.